# Looking for a term, maybe an app

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, system-agnostic, terminology

So my campaign setting uses a major adjustment to the class, subclass, and leveling aspects of 5e.

While all 13 classes cam be chosen, the campaign only has a few subclasses unlocked
I have set up a system to unlock most all the subclasses.

This is all written by hand on college ruled loose leafs, and I'm trying to find a way to make a digital or even typed way of showing this that is legible to someone besides me.

By acquiring a number of levels in a subclass, you can unlock new subclasses. Most could be linier, except when multiple requirements need to be met, and not necessarily from the same branch.

I'm not sure what I should be looking up, because all the games that inspire my set up are just referred to by their own game/community's term for the mechanic.

If I could use a budget application to fill in and connect all the subclasses in the convoluted way I've devised that would be ideal. Because putting it in an excel spread will only improve the reading process slightly, I'd like to keep the positions to better express the relationship between subclasses.

So what do I search for rebuilding a web of words, levels and arrows?

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Feel free to check out our [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how this site works, and don't hesitate to use the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) to answer further questions, or simply ask them in comments or in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question, but if it is about asking for advice on which tool to use, you might want to ask the question on a more traditional forum, since "shopping" questions are off-topic here. If that wasn't the point of the question, reformulating to make it clearer might help attract better answers.

Comment: I'm not sure how inquiring about terminology is shopping.

Comment: I highly recommend checking out the [Are Game Recommendation Questions On Topic, Revisited](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5747) meta, which is also linked in the closure reasons above your question. It should give some explanations on that. I have to admit terminology is pretty difficult to explain in a few words, the way I understand it is that questions that ask for recommendations on tools, games or such are categorized as "shopping", and thus off-topic here (most likely because of their highly subjective and biased nature).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the terms you found from other games/communities? It would only make a difference if you plan on selling/marketing your new system. But if you're just looking for words to describe your idea to the table it doesn't matter. "Hey, I want to use this system I came up with which is like blah in this other RPG."

Comment: @Xisnue whether the question is on topic here, or whether you ask it elsewhere, I suggest being less vague. Legible, not Excel, and "web of words, levels and arrows" are really the only concrete information you're giving about what the software should and shouldn't be capable of... and it's not much to go off of. I bet that if the right person sees a screenshot of your the stuff you wrote on paper, they'll instantly know what kind of software suits your needs.

Comment: My issue seems to be that searching terms used by other games, just results in results that talk about that specific system.

Comment: There really isn't to my knowledge a kind of taxonomist for naming game mechanics, or classifying such arbitrary systems.  It does feel like some graphic you would see in an office meeting like a flow chart, but it's hard to display in a single page, and hard for me to visualize as a flat expression of my scribbles.